# How do I update an mxml property dynamically in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, halo

I'm using Flex 4.0, with the Halo theme, and a custom component that I have the source of. I want to call the component with a parameter to hide or show some items. The parameter is dynamic, meaning it is set in a method after the mxml has loaded.

Snippet:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="absolute"
    xmlns:ns1="de.aggro.components.*"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    initialize="init();"
>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        public var allowwindowmanipulation:Boolean = true;

        internal function init():void {
            allowwindowmanipulation = false;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="st">
        ...
        <ns1:CollapsableTitleWindow width="956" height="395" x="294" y="484" id="wnd" title="title" allowClose="{allowwindowmanipulation}">
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>

</mx:Application>
```

CollapsableTitleWindow code (snippet):

```
public class CollapsableTitleWindow extends Panel implements ICTWindow {    
    public var allowClose:Boolean = true;

    function CollapsableTitleWindow(){
        super();
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, initializeHandler);
    }

    protected override function createChildren():void{
        super.createChildren();         

        //Create the Buttons
        closeButton = new Sprite();

        if(allowClose==true){
            titleBar.addChild(closeButton);
            drawCloseButton(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this code, the value given to the constructor of `CollapsableTitleWindow` is `true` for the `allowClose` variable. So when `createChildren()` is called, the button is drawn.

How can I change the behaviour? I don't mind if the button first gets drawn then later gets removed, if need be, but I don't know how I do this binding of parameter values.

When I for instance change the `title` property to `{allowClose}`, the boolean value of `false` gets shown, even though probably a `true` is passed at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: edited to reflect feedback

Since you're using Flex 4, you should probably do this with a skin and States within the skin.  But if you want to do it through code, try something like this:

```
protected var _allowClose:Boolean=true;
protected var _allowCloseChanged::Boolean=true;
protected var _closeButton:Sprite = new Sprite();


public function get allowClose():Boolean {
    return _allowClose;
}

public function set allowClose(value:Boolean):void {
    if (value != _allowClose) {
       _allowClose=value;
       _allowCloseChanged=true;
       invalidateProperties();
    }
}

override protected function commitProperties():void {
   if (_allowCloseChanged) {
       if (_allowClosed) {
            titlebar.addChild(_closeButton);
            drawCloseButton(true);
       } else {
            titleBar.removeChild(_closeButton);
       }
       //you need to set this back false...sorry I left that out
       _allowCloseChanged=false;
   }
   super.commitProperties();
}
```

Note: in this case, you no longer need to override createChildren

Comment: I'm investigating your solution as we speak, it appears to be called correctly, but the rest of my code (that i didn't include in the snippet) that should happen inside near the "drawCloseButton" code, is currently failing, so i'm fixing that first..

Comment: Joy, it works! (I had to fiddle a bit with my own code.) Two things however: commitProperties should be "protected override" instead of "public", and inside the "if (_allowCloseChanged) {" should be a "_allowCloseChanged = false;" Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, wrote this too early in the morning :). The reason you had to change it to (!_allowCloseChanged) is because I forgot to set it back false in the commitProperties. You want to run that code whenever _allowClose changes (hence the flag), *not* every time commitProperties runs (which is often).